# Display module form on admin pages. Drupal 7. Commerce.

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I've created a small module that I would like to link account notes with users.

I have written the beginnings of the module that includes a form for adding notes and date created. This works when I access mydomain.com/admin/user_notes.

My question is, how do I get this form to display in the admin section of the site on a users orders history page. eg mydomain.com/users/1245/order-history

I would like our admins who have a specific role to be able to add notes when they view a users order history page.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Thanks Oh no. My installation had hidden regions, so I couldn't see the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a block, create one with the hook_block_info and hook_block_view function.

Like this:

```
function tips_block_info() {
  $block['yourBlockName'] = array(
      'info' => t('This my created block'), 
      'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE, // Disable caching if you need/want to
  );

  return $block;
}
```

Thisby will create an empty block, to fill it with content use hook_block_view:

```
function moduleName_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

  switch($delta) {
    // The delta of your block will be the key from the $block array we set in hook_block_info
    case 'yourBlockName':
      // Set the block title
      $block['subject'] = 'Hey I\'m your block title';
      $block['content'] = 'Block content goes here can also be the output of any function';   
    break;
  }

  return $block;
}
```

Don't forget to set access permission for your block if you need any, you can do that by editing the block on the block admin page.

Relevant Drupal API links:

[hook_block_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7)

[hook_block_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7)